# How to download file without opening in new tab in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, download

I am trying to download file but it is opening in new tab, but here I want to download file directly.

What I have tried

```html
 <a href={api_Url+'/SurveyImages/'+link} target = "_blank" download ={link}>{link}</a>
```

if I remove `target = "_blank"` then it replacing the file with my application tab.

How can I directly download it?

Answer (score 3):

Best solution as per new chrome specification https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations

Convert this code in React.

Vanilla  JavaScript

```
public static downloadFile(url: string): void {
     const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
       if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
         const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(xmlHttp.response);
         const e = document.createElement('a');
         e.href = blobUrl;
         e.download = blobUrl.substr(blobUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
         document.body.appendChild(e);
         e.click();
         document.body.removeChild(e);
       }
     };
     xmlHttp.responseType = 'blob';
     xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
     xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
```

If you're using angular try this.

```
async downloadBrochure(url: string) {
    try {
      const res = await this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();
      this.downloadFile(res);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.body.message);
    }
  }

  downloadFile(data) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const e = document.createElement('a');
    e.href = url;
    e.download = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.click();
    document.body.removeChild(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

your code:

```
target = "_blank"
```

solution:

```
target = "_self"
```

Comment: if it replaces the tab, then it has something to do with the `href={api_Url+'/SurveyImages/'+link}` I tried different scenarios here. download and target is not the problem anymore.

Comment: yes... from what I believe, `href` must be starting at something like this `data:image/png;base64,`

Comment: but how can  be it start from `data:image/png;base64,` because file path coming from sever like `http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:4000/SurveyImages/1568613624680download.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Click to download
This is not supported on all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a tags.

Try this:
    axios({
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/static/example.pdf',
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'blob', // important
    }).then((response) => {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    });

Reference: https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743

Comment: @patambut what would I get as  response even I have link of file here`/http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:4000/SurveyImages/1568613624680download.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You can try "HTML  download Attribute"

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

```
<a href="myfile.jpg" download="">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not working as I am expecting

Comment: Can you put your code on jsfiddle/codepen?

or Can you show me the console window of the browser. 

There might be some event override